# The code doesnt load after while PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the folowing code in PHP, thats is suposed to recover some data from the database and fill a select and generate divs with the content, but after the first while the page doesnt load anymore.

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$sql="SELECT idMoto, modelo, ano, fabricante, preco, disponibilidade, imagem FROM motos";
$motos=mysql_query($sql,$conn); 

echo("<div class='row'>");
echo("<div class='col s2'>");
echo("<p>Filtrar por: </p>");   
echo("</div>");
echo("<div class='input-field col s3'>");
echo("<select>");
echo("<option value='' disabled selected>Selecione o fabricante</option>");

$fabricantesRepetidos="";
$numFabricante = 0;
while($linhaFabricantes=mysql_fetch_array($motos)){
    if(in_array($linhaFabricantes['fabricante'], $fabricantesRepetidos)){
        return false;
    } else {
        echo("<option value='".$linhaFabricantes['fabricante']."'>".$linhaFabricantes['fabricante']."</option>");
        $numFabricante++;
        $fabricantesRepetidos[$numFabricante] = $linhaFabricantes['fabricante'];
    }
}         
echo("</select>");
echo("<label>Fabricante</label>");
echo("</div>");
echo("</div>");

while ($linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($motos)){
    echo("<div class='col s12 m12'>");
    echo("<div class='card horizontal'>");
    echo("<div class='card-image'>");
    echo ("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $linha['imagem'] )."' width='256' height='256'/>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("<div class='card-stacked'>");
    echo("<div class='card-content'>");
    echo("<p><b>Fabricante:</b> ".$linha['fabricante']."</br> <b>Modelo:</b> ".$linha['modelo']."</br><b>Ano: </b>".$linha['ano']."</br><b>Preço: </b>".$linha['preco']." Reais</br><b>disponibilidade: </b>".$linha['disponibilidade']."</br></p>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("<div class='card-action'>");
    echo("<a href=''>Editar</a>");
    echo("<a href=''>Excluir</a>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("</div>");     
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

That's how the page looks with the error
[image: That's how the page looks with the error]

And that's how the page looks if i delete the first while
[image: And that's how the page looks if i delete the first while]

P.S: I have to use MYSQL.

Comment: You probably have an error. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the **top** of your PHP script

Comment: There is likely a PHP error being thrown there. Either enable on-page reporting or check your PHP error log.

Comment: You have a `return` inside your `while` loop. That will stop execution at that point in the code. Did you mean to use `break` or `continue`? What is it you were intending to happen at that point in the code?

Comment: Looking closer, I'd say you want `continue;`. Why don't you just do a `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate records?

Comment: Also, you cannot iterate the results of a query (ie `$motos`) twice. At least, not without `mysql_data_seek($motos, 0)` between

Comment: Why do you _"have to use MYSQL"_? Surely MySQLi or PDO is also available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try following code

```
<?php
                        include("db.php");
                        $sql="SELECT idMoto, modelo, ano, fabricante, preco, disponibilidade, imagem FROM motos";
                        $motos=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                        $motos1=mysql_query($sql,$conn);  

                        echo("<div class='row'>");
                            echo("<div class='col s2'>");
                                echo("<p>Filtrar por: </p>");   
                            echo("</div>");
                            echo("<div class='input-field col s3'>");
                                echo("<select>");
                                    echo("<option value='' disabled selected>Selecione o fabricante</option>");

                                        $fabricantesRepetidos="";
                                        $numFabricante = 0;
                                        while($linhaFabricantes=mysql_fetch_array($motos)){
                                            if(in_array($linhaFabricantes['fabricante'], $fabricantesRepetidos)){
                                                return false;
                                            }else{
                                                echo("<option value='".$linhaFabricantes['fabricante']."'>".$linhaFabricantes['fabricante']."</option>");
                                                $numFabricante++;
                                                $fabricantesRepetidos[$numFabricante] = $linhaFabricantes['fabricante'];
                                            }
                                        }         
                                echo("</select>");
                                echo("<label>Fabricante</label>");
                            echo("</div>");
                        echo("</div>");

                        while ($linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($motos1)){
                            echo("<div class='col s12 m12'>");
                                echo("<div class='card horizontal'>");
                                    echo("<div class='card-image'>");
                                        echo ("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $linha['imagem'] )."' width='256' height='256'/>");
                                    echo("</div>");
                                    echo("<div class='card-stacked'>");
                                        echo("<div class='card-content'>");
                                            echo("<p><b>Fabricante:</b> ".$linha['fabricante']."</br> <b>Modelo:</b> ".$linha['modelo']."</br><b>Ano: </b>".$linha['ano']."</br><b>Preço: </b>".$linha['preco']." Reais</br><b>disponibilidade: </b>".$linha['disponibilidade']."</br></p>");
                                        echo("</div>");
                                        echo("<div class='card-action'>");
                                            echo("<a href=''>Editar</a>");
                                            echo("<a href=''>Excluir</a>");
                                        echo("</div>");
                                    echo("</div>");
                                echo("</div>");
                            echo("</div>");     
                        }
                        mysql_close($conn);
                    ?>
```